# Given a polynomial $P(x,y) = \sum\limits_{m,n = 0} {{a_{mn}}{x^m}{y^n}} $

Tags: real-analysis

Given a polynomial $P(x,y) = \sum\limits_{m,n = 0} {{a_{mn}}{x^m}{y^n}} $ in the variables x,y and an $\varepsilon  > 0$ , find an explicit $\delta  > 0$ establishing uniform continuity on the square ${[ - R,R]^2}$.

how i begin for do it ? thank

Answer (score 1):

One way is to start by finding a suitable bound on the individual terms $x^m y^n$.

Suppose we can find an $L$ such that $|x_1^m y_1^n - x_2^m y_2^n| \le L \|(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)\|$ for all $m,n$ and $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in [-R,R]^2$.

Then you have $|P(x_1,y_1)-P(x_2,y_2)| \le |\sum_{m,n} a_{mn} (x_1^m y_1^n)-x_2^m y_2^n) ) | \le (L \sum_{m,n} |a_{mn}|) \|(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)\|$, from which you can choose an explicit $\delta>0$.

To see how we can find the $L$, we use the mean value theorem on $\phi((x,y))= x^my^n$ to bound $|\phi((x_1,y_1))-\phi((x_2,y_2))|$ in $[-R,R]^2$. This will give some $L_{mn}$, then let $L = \max_{m,n} L_{mn}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\max(R,1)$.

- For every $|x_1|\leqslant R$, $|x_2|\leqslant R$ and $m\leqslant N$, $$|x_1^m-x_2^m|\leqslant NS^{N-1}|x_1-x_2|.$$
- For every $|x_1|\leqslant R$, $|x_2|\leqslant R$, $|y|\leqslant R$, $n\leqslant N$ and $m\leqslant N$, $$|x_1^my^n-x_2^my^n|\leqslant |y^m|\cdot|x_1^m-x_2^m|\leqslant NS^{2N-1}|x_1-x_2|.$$
- For every $|x_1|\leqslant R$, $|x_2|\leqslant R$, $|y_1|\leqslant R$,  $|y_2|\leqslant R$, $n\leqslant N$ and $m\leqslant N$, $$|x_1^my_1^n-x_2^my_2^n|\leqslant|x_1^m|\cdot|y_1^n-y_2^n|+|y_2^n|\cdot|x_1^m-x_2^m|\leqslant NS^{2N-1}(|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|).$$
- For every polynomial $P$ of degree at most $N$ and every $|x_1|\leqslant R$, $|x_2|\leqslant R$, $|y_1|\leqslant R$,  $|y_2|\leqslant R$, $$|P(x_1,y_1)-P(x_2,y_2)|\leqslant\sum\limits_{m,n}|a_{m,n}|\cdot|x_1^my_1^n-x_2^my_2^n|,$$ hence $$|P(x_1,y_1)-P(x_2,y_2)|\leqslant\sum\limits_{m,n}|a_{m,n}|\cdot NS^{2N-1}(|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|).$$

Thus, if $|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|\leqslant\delta$ then $$|P(x_1,y_1)-P(x_2,y_2)|\leqslant A(P)N(P)S^{2N-1}\delta,$$ where $A(P)=\sum\limits_{m,n}|a_{m,n}|$ and $N(P)$ is the degree of $P$. 
To get a final upper bound of $\varepsilon$, one can choose $\delta=$ $____$.